# RobotFrameWork: Open Browser tab does not work

Tags: robotframework

When I type in:

`Open browser tab`  the text in Eclipse doesn't turn blue.

How to do this?

Comment: Did you implemented this keyword because there is no such in the Selenium Library?

Comment: In FR, only keyword `Open Browser` is available under selenium library. What do you mean by `Open Browser tab`? Is this your custom keyword?

Answer (score 0):

```
Open Browser  Chrome/Firefox
```

Make sure you have put webdriver into pythonpath

Refernece here : 
http://robotframework.org/Selenium2Library/Selenium2Library.html#Open%20Browser

Answer (score 0):

The reason is there is no keyword named "Open Browser Tab". The keyword "Open browser" is available to use.

If you want to use an "Open Browser Tab" keyword, you need to define it under your custom made keywords

```
*** Keywords ***
Open Browser Tab
    #Do this
```